# Why converting individual characters of a string to integer using "Convert.ToInt32()" method gives weird result in C#?

Tags: c#

Here is sample code:

```
    using System;

    namespace MessingWithFourDigitNumbers
    {
        class FourDigitManipulation
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                string numString = "1234";
                for(int i = 0; i < numString.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(numString[i]));
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Result was:[Weird Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p8IF.png)

49

50

51

52

Instead of:

1

2

3

4

Comment: You aren't converting strings to integers, you're casting `Char` values to their numeric equivalents. `String[i]` returns a *Char*, not a string

Comment: Use `Convert.ToInt32(numString[i].ToString())`. You may also use `int.Parse()` (or int.TryParse()` if the input might not always be an integer) instead of `Convert.ToInt32()`.

Comment: Because of ASCII values. ASCII values of '1', '2', '3' are 49, 50, 51 43 respectively

Comment: Use Console.WriteLine(numString[i] - ‘0’)